# Returning back to main activity from gameover screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent, return, program-entry-point

Hi so even though I have seen a couple of topics about linking activities or returning I can not get my return back to activity to work. I abit of back ground the the app when the user gets an answer wrong or runs out of time it goes to game over taking the score across with it and displaying it on the game over, here's the working code for that if it helps solve my issue:
Main Class:

```
 public void fail(){
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,gameover.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("number", score);


            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();

        }
```

gameover class:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
re_run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);
        EndScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);
        int getVal;
        getVal = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");
        String s = String.valueOf( getVal );
        EndScore.setText(s);     
  }
```

Now the reason I shared the above working code because I have the feeling the intent that takes the user and score to the gameover screen, is messing with the retry/return code as shown below:

```
private void setButtonOnClickListeners(){
          re_run.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent retry = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(retry);

            }
        });
}
```

From what I can find from those topics these seems to be the correct method. but when the code is run the re_run button does nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use "`setButtonOnClickListeners()`" to implement setOnClickListener and so override the onClick. But when did you call setButtonOnClickListeners?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.gameover);    re_run = (Button) 
    findViewById(R.id.retry);    
    EndScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);    
    int getVal;    
    getVal = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");   
    String s = String.valueOf( getVal );    
    EndScore.setText(s);    
    setButtonOnClickListeners();
    }
```

You can maybe check that your OnClick is working correctly adding a log line in LogCat. `Log.d("GameOver", "Retry onclick ok");`

Comment: WOW how embarrassing i didn't setButtonOnClickListeners() for the gameover class... just shows how easy it can be to look over a simple mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are finding a view before it was inflated (R.id.retry).

Change the sequence of commands to:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
re_run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);
```

Also try changing the intent to:

```
Intent retry = new Intent(GameOver.this, MainActivity.class);
retry.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: @Phil3992 try the updated answer. Otherwise post your MainActivity in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I personally used `startActivityForResult(Intent)` to start the game over screen, and once the player inputted his name or pressed something or quit the activity with Back, then it returned a value to `onActivityResult(..)` in which I called `finish()`.

EDIT:

Game ends, so I started activity using

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("Score", scoreCount);
            i.setClass(context, HighScoreInputActivity.class);
            context.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Then when you insert the scores and stuff, you close the game screen in `GameActivity` with

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: But there are better ways to go at it using some sort of intent flag which will clear all other activities on top.